# PHP escaping characters

Tags: php, javascript

I've read through similar threads, but I can't figure out how to escape the characters in the following string:

```
$var =  '<a href="'.$confUrl.'/index.php?a=profile&u='.$TMPL['username'].'&r=2"></a>';
```

For some reason `href` isn't working, but somehow `window.location.assign(x)` is.

I'm trying to turn the above, invalid, code into the following:

```
$var =  '<a onclick="window.location.assign('.$confUrl.'/index.php?a=profile&u='.$TMPL['username'].'&r=2')"></a>';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't surround your URL with quotes. It should be:

```
$var =  '<a onclick="window.location.assign(\''.$confUrl.'/index.php?a=profile&u='. urlencode($TMPL['username']) . '&r=2\'')"></a>';
```

so the browser will render:

```
<a onclick="window.location.assign('someURL/index.php?a=profile&u=someUsername&r=2')"></a>
```

Note that you should include something between start tag and end tag of `<a>`.

**UPDATE:** Yes, [urlencode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) is suggested to avoid unwanted characters in the URL.